# Is it possible to make a single vertex a different colour using gplot in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I am using gplot to plot a graph of an adjacency matrix in the following manner:

```
XY = <coordinates>
A = <adjacency matrix>
gplot(A,XY,'-o');
```

which gives me the following plot:

[image]

I was wondering, if I have a list T of vertexes that should be coloured red, can I represent them on this graph? or would i have to plot all the vertexes without symbols, then plot all the blue vertexes and then plot all the red ones separately?

that works, but its a bit annoying to have to do it that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do it separately. The [`LineSpec`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linespec.html) do no support multiple colors for different markers, unfortunately (i.e.  `gplot(A,XY,'-o','MarkerFaceColor,[1 0 0; 0 0 1]);` is very forbidden).

Still it should not be more complicated than extra 2 lines:

```
gplot(A,XY,'-o');
hold on
gplot(Ared,XYred,'-o','MarkerFaceColor,[1 0 0]);
```

Comment: thanks, i ended up just using something pretty similar, i was just hoping that you could do it all in one go, never mind!